# Make Windows start a .exe at booting fast

Tags: windows, autostart

I bought a notebook recently and will give it to someone else on their birthday. That person, however, is not good with computers yet and so I wanted to create a full-screen app that would introduce them to the computer. The app works perfect, the thing is just that I need it to start when logging in to their account (just once, too, obviously).

I know there's a folder in which you can place executables that then will be executed at login, however, that is simply ***not fast enough***.

When the PC boots and the automatic login is done, the desktop is shown for about 3 minutes until the full-screen app finally opens (the laptop is not really a powerhouse tbh though).

How can I make it open the app faster? Or could I maybe make Windows not start explorer.exe until my app is open? Thanks.

(OS is Windows 10)

Comment: I am not sure if this is the way to go. I know, that services are launched earlier than apps on login/startup, therefore it might be better to code some simple service which launches your exe maybe even before the desktop showing up. Can't tell you anything more specific, but maybe this will help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the registry to accomplish this.

You can modify the "Shell" key at

`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon`
to the full path of your program.

This should replace explorer.exe and your program should start "explorer.exe" and set this registry's value back to "explorer.exe" after it's started.

References:

1. [How can I start up Windows without explorer loading up?](https://superuser.com/questions/107611/how-can-i-start-up-windows-without-explorer-loading-up)

Comment: Thanks! The problem is just that the value won't get set back to "explorer.exe" as I just saw...

Comment: Do you mean the computer is kind of trapped in your program now? Well, you can start the Task manager with ctrl + alt + del and then run regedit or explorer.exe from that task manager.

Comment: Oh never mind, I thought it would get set back "explorer.exe" automatically again, I didn't catch the "your program" part in your answer, sorry :D

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple ways to do this.

One is by using registry. You can add necessary registry entry under:
HKEY_CURENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunOnce
This would run your application right after the user logs in.

Another one would be to create a new task through Task Scheduler:
When creating tasks you have lots of option to control when it starts. You can start it at log-on of specific user, you can start it even before user log-on so you can explain the user of how to properly log-on to the computer, etc.
You can also control if this task is executed once or every time.

I personally would go for second option as it does not require any manual registry editing and therefore it can be setup even on non-administrative account.